# view Component rendered early not waiting for await methods result in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, components

Hi I am using first time view Component in my Dotnet core application to get API result data to view. I have created a class and calling await API call but view render early and not wait for api response.

```
namespace Gut.Web.Components
{
    public class OneWayResultViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        #region Fields
        private readonly IApiAggregatorService _apiAggregatorService;
        private readonly IWorkContext _workContext;
        private readonly ITravelApiProviderService _travelApiProviderService;
        #endregion

        #region Ctor
        public OneWayResultViewComponent(IApiAggregatorService apiAggregatorService, IWorkContext workContext, ITravelApiProviderService travelApiProviderService)
        {
            _apiAggregatorService = apiAggregatorService;
            _workContext = workContext;
            _travelApiProviderService = travelApiProviderService;
        }
        #endregion
        #region Methods
        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string sessionid)
        {
            var searchFlightDetails = await _apiAggregatorService.GetCacheSearchFlightDetailsByIdAsync(sessionid);
            var travelers = _travelApiProviderService.GetActiveProvider();
            var response = _apiAggregatorService.SearchOneWay(travelers, searchFlightDetails).Result;
            return View(response);
        }

        public override 
        #endregion
    }
}
```

so I need to show response to view. I have search on google but didn't find a way to reupdate component. Example found to call component by jQuery. If jQuery is required so I can call **partialview** then why component.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the view component is returning "early" because your last call should've contained an `await`:

```
var response = await _apiAggregatorService.SearchOneWay(travelers, searchFlightDetails);
```

Comment: Jonathan Sapp that I'm saying but I don't want to early rendering view coz its null and after few sec data is coming from api then how I update or reupdate component. i hope you getting my point.